# In HttpRoute resource, use regexMatch captured group in URLRewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-gateway-api

I am moving from an nginx ingress controller to a Gateway controller in GKE. In my Ingress resource, I do a URL rewrite using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation. In the rewrite, I use the regex capture group that is outputted from the rules http path.

In the HttpRoute resource, I see ways to do this with a PathPrefix, but I don't see a way to use the regexMatch "output" (captured group) in the rewrite. I only see those 2 options in the rewrite: `pathPrefixRewrite`  and `hostRewrite` .

Is there a way to have a rewrite based on the regex captured group?

Example:
Rewriting `/before/(.*)/ending`
to `/after/$1/ending`

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#limitations) under limitation and known issue, regular expression is not supported by GKE gateway. However I think you can use Nginx reverse proxy to handle this complex rewriting with regex using the annotation you shared then point it to GKE Gateway as the backend.

Comment: Facing same issue DavidGourde .Do you find the solution ? @YvanG. can you elaborate How NGINX reverse proxy can be used?